# Controlling the response body in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a very simple webservice which consists of a single post endpoint:

```
  @POST(PROTOCOL)
  Call<POST> addMaintenanceProtocol(@Body MaintenanceProtocolItem proto);
```

When I invoke it I get the onFailure method called with the following exception:

```
02-12 19:57:04.214 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
02-12 19:57:04.214 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1559)
02-12 19:57:04.214 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1401)
02-12 19:57:04.214 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:593)
02-12 19:57:04.214 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
02-12 19:57:04.214 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:205)
02-12 19:57:04.214 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
02-12 19:57:04.214 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
02-12 19:57:04.214 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
02-12 19:57:04.214 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
02-12 19:57:04.214 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:112)
02-12 19:57:04.214 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:141)
02-12 19:57:04.214 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
02-12 19:57:04.215 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
02-12 19:57:04.215 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
02-12 19:57:04.215 5069-5069/com.example.nborisov.perfectelectra W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

This is due to the return body of this endpoint being a pdf file and not a GSON or to be more general a raw stream of bytes. How can I make retrofit not try to deserialize the response body to a gson object. On the server I can see that the actual POST request has succeeded it's just that the client is having hard time parsing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For downloading file using retrofit2... use `@Streaming` annotation..and make it call for a `ResponseBody` object instead of `Post`..

`@POST(PROTOCOL)
  @Streaming
  Call<ResponseBody> addMaintenanceProtocol(@Body     MaintenanceProtocolItem proto);`

Comment: Will try this, but I also modified my server to not return a PDF but rather just a plain http response code, now the exception I'm getting is java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $. Apart from handling such "expected" exception is there something else I can do to "silence" the response. I.e. only care about return http status code and nothing else?

Comment: after sending a plain http response ... still `onFailure()` is getting called ??